# Stop jQuery animate function within setInterval and assign css opacity to 0

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem setting opacity to 0 after animate function in jQuery finished changing opacity value from 0 to 1. Any help would be appreciated.

```
var i = -1;
var interval = setInterval($.proxy(function () {
    i++;
    if (i >= this.options.slices) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        this.$element.children("[class='" + this.options.clonesClass + "']" ).css("opacity", 0);
    } else {
        this.$element.children("[data-index='" + i + "']").stop().animate({ opacity: 1 }, 1000);
    }
}, this), 50)
```

Comment: Code sample is not enough. Would be easier to understand what you need if you described a desired behavior in comparison to current one.

Comment: This is my original div container <div class="aSlider-clone" data-index="2" style="width: 90px; opacity: 0; left: 180px;"></div>, the animate function brings opacity to 1. When the action is finished I want to change it to 0.

Comment: If lets say I use animate({opacity:0}, 100) after it finished it works but css("opacity", 0) doesn't it sort of like animate function overrides the css one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the only way I managed to achieve the result I wanted.

```
var t = this;
t.$element.children( "[class='" + t.options.clonesClass + "']" ).each( $.proxy( function () {


    setTimeout( $.proxy( function () {
        i++;
        if ( i < t.options.slices ) {
            $( this ).animate( { opacity: 1 }, 1000 )

        } else {
            $( this ).animate( { opacity: 1 }, 1000, function () {
                t.$element.children( "[class='" + t.options.clonesClass + "']" ).css( "opacity", 0 );
            } );
        }


    }, this ), timeBuffer );
    timeBuffer += 50;


} ), this );
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look in [animate docs](http://api.jquery.com/animate/). If what you want to achieve is performing an action after animate completes, then pass a function performing that action as a last argument to `animate`.

So basically this

```
this.$element.children("[data-index='" + i + "']").stop().animate({ opacity: 1 }, 1000)
```

should become something like

```
this.$element.children("[data-index='" + i + "']").stop().animate({ opacity: 1 }, 1000, function(){
    $element.css({opacity:0});
})
```

**Edit**:

Working with intervals is not really required with jQuery. Assumming the element you want to animate is `$element`, just execute

```
$element.stop().animate({ opacity: 1 }, 1000, function(){
    $element.css({opacity:0});
})
```

**Edit**:

To achieve what you describe in a comment you need to chain animate calls in a sequence. I would recommend a recursive construct like this (pseudo code):

```
function myAnimate(elementsArray, num) {
  if (num < elementsArray.size) {
    $(elementsArray[num]).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 1000, function(){
      myAnimate(elementsArray, num + 1);
    })
  } else {
    for each el in elementsArray {
      $(el).css({opacity:0});
    }
    // do other things, like prepare for next iteration
    // then maybe call myAnimate(elementsArray, 0)
    // to start all over again
  }
}
```

then call it like this

```
myAnimate($('div.toBeAnimated'), 0)
```

Comment: I have 12 div that act as slices, each of them is switching opacity 0 to 1 one after another when all of this slices have opacity value of 1, I want to have all of them change opacity to 0 at once thats why I use setInterval.

Comment: but in this case all of the elements will animate to opacity 1 without delay, they will animate almost simultaneously. In jsfiddle you can see witch effect I am trying to achieve. After that effect is over I need to set opacity to zero so that I can change innerHTML with new contents and repeat the effect.

Comment: No, they won't. Since the recursive call is put into a callback, it is executed **after** `animate` of previous element completes. That's how the callback mechanism should work. Do `callback()` after actual work is done.

Comment: Ok I understand basically when animate will finish it will call back myAnimate and start the process again and when all of the elements go through process it will set opacity to 0, but then I can't have than 2 element animating at the same time with delay  setting. I know I am making it more difficult but I really appreciate your help, you just pushed my understanding to next level thanks.